non-unicode fonts displaying as gibberish in Windows 10 guest running in qemu
I have a Hebrew app that uses non-unicode fonts, and when I run it in my Windows 10 guest, which is managed by virt-manager, it started displaying gibberish, although it used to work right. I tried reinstalling the app, to no avail.
I have the system locale in the Windows guest set to Hebrew.
When I run this same app in VirtualBox, or VMware, the fonts display properly. The issue is only on qemu.
I have this issue on various debian-based hosts.
So does this sound like a qemu issue, or is it just happening coincidentally on my qemu guest?

It's not a qemu issue. Windows needs to be switched to Hebrew as the system language. The user account can be English, or whatever, but the system language needs to be Hebrew.
